# Как слить список списков в один список?

Tags: c#

У меня есть список списков:

```
List<List<Data>> data;
```

где Data это структура struct Data { ... }. Как проще всего слить эти списки воедино?

```
List<Data> united;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var united = data.Aggregate((a, b) => { a.AddRange(b); return a; });
```

или так

```
var united = (from а in data
              from b in а
              select b).ToList();
```

Comment: функциональщина какая-то %) но выглядит красиво :-)

Answer (score 10):

Можно ещё проще:

```
uinted = data.SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```